# Validate two different values of Text without duplicating the test

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

If a site has two locales, GB and US, and there is a label text we need to assert, where GB says “My dashboard” and the US says “My Dashboard”, how do we validate these text values without duplicating the test?

Comment: If you are not interested in the case, you can convert to to e.g. lowercase and than assert it against one expected value.

Comment: its not only the case. sometimes the text displayed is different from GB to US as well. but its the same field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As for "My dashboard" / "My Dashboard", the easiest way to do that is to use the `toLowerCase()` method (@pavelsman comment):

```js
await t.expect(title.innerText.toLowerCase()).eql('my dashboard');
```

2. If you have a complex case, you can use [regex matching](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402723/reference/test-api/testcontroller/expect/match) or the [`.contains()` method](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402729/reference/test-api/testcontroller/expect/contains):

```js
await t.expect(title.innerText).match(yourRegex);
await t.expect(title.innerText).contains(sameStringPartForBothCases);
```

3. If that doesn't suit you, then you might want to arrange your expected values as objects to assert **the full title string**:

```js
import { userVariables } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Fixture`;

test('test', async t => {
    const expectedTitle = {
        'en-GB': 'My dashboard',
        'en-US': 'My Dashboard'
    };

    await t.expect(title.innerText).eql(expectedTitle[userVariables.currentLocale]);
});
```

In this case, you need to run TestCafe with some of the [`.testcaferc.json`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file) files.

The "en-GB" configuration contains:

```json
{
  "browsers": "chrome --lang=en-GB",
  "userVariables": {
    "currentLocale": "en-GB"
  }
}
```

The "en-US" configuration contains:

```json
{
  "browsers": "chrome --lang=en-US",
  "userVariables": {
    "currentLocale": "en-US"
  }
}
```

Reference: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#uservariables